# Does the meaning of "to allow" and "to enable" coincide in this context?

Tags: word-usage, usage, verbs

The sentence:

> It allows / enables the use of more advanced algorithms.

Is there a difference whether *allow* or *enable* is used or are they mutually exchangeable? What are the differences in detail in this and similar contexts?

Answer (score 1):

At first, I thought that 'enable' requires a direct object. That is, *enables **who***? But then, after referring dictionaries, I think yes, they are interchangeable in this context.

[OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/enable?q=enable) entry:

> The software ***enables you*** to create your own DVDs. 
>  a new train line to ***enable easier access*** to the stadium

Also, see ['allow' is the synonym of 'enable'.](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/enable?q=enable)